# Adding many zero service-time elements to an M/M/1 queue

Tags: queueing-theory

I am trying to make sense of the following setting.

M/M/1 queue.  $\lambda$: arrival rate, $s=1/\mu$: average service time.  Then, the mean waiting time in the queue is: $w_q={{\rho^2} \over {1-\rho}} \cdot {1 \over \lambda}$ (for $\rho = \lambda s$).

Now suppose we increase the arrival rate by a factor of $c$, but all the additional elements have zero service time. Denote the new parameters with $\hat{\square}$.  Then, $\hat{s}=s/c$, $\hat{\lambda}=c\lambda$.  So, $\hat{\rho}=\rho$.  So,  $\hat{w}_q=w_q/c$.

But why?  Suppose that $\rho$ is near 1. So, the server is busy most of the time.  So, the new elements will be essentially waiting just like the old ones.  So, why does the average waiting time fall so dramatically?

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: If a proportion of customers have $0$ service time and others not then you do not have an $M/M/1$ queue and your expression for $w_q$ would not apply.

Comment: Ok.  So, this is the answer to my question.  Thanks.

Comment: If instead both the arrival rate $\lambda$ and service rate $\mu$ in an $M/M/1$ queue both increased by a factor of $c$ it is true that the mean waiting time would fall.   For example if the arrival rate was $1$ (per minute) and the service rate $2$ (per minute) then expected waiting time would be $\frac12$ (minutes).  Multiply the numbers in the rates by $60$ without changing anything and if the arrival rate was $60$ (per hour) and the service rate $120$ (per hour) then the expected waiting time would be $\frac{1}{120}$ (hours).